# When pulling to refresh the indexPath.row in cellForRowAt method is returning the incorrect value

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am a trainee iOS Developer, so there are some  things that I still don't understand very well.
I'm creating a Contacts app where the names are displayed within sections just like the original one but with the addition of deletion feature.

I have the following problem:

If I have a contact alone in a section like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i8AU.png) I delete it on swipe and every thing is just fine. But If I add this same contact on device's Contact app and then go back to my app and pull down to refresh to add update the table in my app I get the **Fatal error: Index out of range**, the app crashes and gets stuck with the activity indicator loading.

Here is the code:

**How I populate the data source on my manager class**

```
func addContactsToDictionary(from arrayOfContacts: [Contact]) {
    for contact in arrayOfContacts {
        let contactsKey = String(contact.firstName.prefix(1))       // Getting each given name's first letter
        if var contactsValue = contactsDictionary[contactsKey] {    // if there's already a value for the current key
            contactsValue.append(contact)     // Creating a value array of given names for the dictionary
            contactsDictionary[contactsKey] = contactsValue     // Adding a value array of given names to the current key in the dictionary
        } else {
            contactsDictionary[contactsKey] = [contact]
        }
    }
    createAndSortSectionsArray()
}

func createAndSortSectionsArray() {
    sectionTitles = [String](contactsDictionary.keys)
    sectionTitles = sectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1})
}
```

**Action method for the Refresh control, located on Table view's controller**

```
@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("Attempting to refresh data")
    let delay = 1

    self.contactManager.contactsDictionary.removeAll()  // To avoid duplicated data
    self.contactManager.fetchContacts { (response, error) in
        if let errorToCatch = error {
            UITableViewController.Alert.showFetchingErrorAlert(on: self, message: errorToCatch.localizedDescription)
        } else if let contactsArray = response {
            self.contactManager.addContactsToDictionary(from: contactsArray)
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(delay)) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.myRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

**Table View Controller's Extension for data source**

```
extension ContactsTableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let contactsInitialAsKey = contactManager.sectionTitles[indexPath.section]

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        contactManager.deleteContacts(at: indexPath)
        contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactsInitialAsKey]!.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


        if indexPath.row == 0 && contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactsInitialAsKey]!.isEmpty {
            contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactsInitialAsKey] = nil
            contactManager.sectionTitles.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    contactManager.sectionTitles[section]
}

override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return contactManager.sectionTitles
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return contactManager.sectionTitles.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let contactKey = contactManager.sectionTitles[section]
    guard let contactValues = contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactKey] else { return 0 }
    print(contactValues.map({ $0.firstName }), contactValues.count)
    return contactValues.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    let contactKey = contactManager.sectionTitles[indexPath.section]

    cell.contactsViewController = self
    cell.setStarButton()
    cell.setImageView()

    if let contacts = contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactKey] {
        print(contactKey, contacts.map { $0.firstName }, indexPath.section, indexPath.row) 
        cell.setDataToContactCell(contactData: contacts[indexPath.row]) // Where I get the Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

So far I was only able to find the possible problem doing the following:

> print(contactKey, contacts.map { $0.firstName }, indexPath.section, indexPath.row)

to see what was happening and this is what the log is showing me

```
Attempting to refresh data
Attempting to fetch contacts today...
Access granted
G ["Guga"] 2 1 //Here I noticed that for some reason the indexPath.row is not returning the correct value
Fatal error: Index out of range
2020-01-10 07:10:59.976537+0300 myContacts[12858:351184] Fatal error: Index out of range
```

I looked a lot of similar posts, but in most of them the issue with indexPath.row was related to clicking a button to get it. So I didn't find a fitting solution and I don't know how to solve this problem.

I'd really appreciate it if you help me. 
Thank you!

Comment: That's probably because you are not making changes to your data source after the user deletes a row with the table view.

Comment: Could you tell me how could I do that? @ElTomato

Comment: @ElTomato didn't I do that in the commit editingStyle method? the changes to the data source. Or it should be done in another place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem making the following changes in data source extension.

**1. Removing the verification for empty array of values in contacts dictionary from "commit editingStyles method"**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let contactKey = contactManager.sectionTitles[indexPath.section]

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        contactManager.deleteContacts(at: indexPath)
        contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactKey]!.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

**2.Moving it to titleForHeaderInSection and "hiding" the title for those sections**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let contactKey = contactManager.sectionTitles[section]
    guard let contactValues = contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactKey] else { return nil }

    return contactValues.isEmpty ? nil : contactManager.sectionTitles[section]
}
```

**3.And moving it to numberOfRowsInSection method and returning 0 for those sections**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let contactKey = contactManager.sectionTitles[section]
    guard let contactValues = contactManager.contactsDictionary[contactKey] else { return 0 }

    return contactValues.isEmpty ? 0 : contactValues.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your handleRefresh() code like this. Remove the data from your contacts dictionary only if you have got the response successfully. Once the response is received and stored in your contactsDictionary, reload your tableview.

```
@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("Attempting to refresh data")
    let delay = 1

    self.contactManager.fetchContacts { (response, error) in
      if let errorToCatch = error {
        UITableViewController.Alert.showFetchingErrorAlert(on: self, message: errorToCatch.localizedDescription)
      } else if let contactsArray = response {
        self.contactManager.contactsDictionary.removeAll()  // To avoid duplicated data
        self.contactManager.addContactsToDictionary(from: contactsArray)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.myRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: But if I want to have some delay on the refresh?

Comment: No.  If you do that, you will revert to the original date set, and you will go back to square one.

Comment: Your suggestion is causing the opposite. All the contacts where removed and only the recently added was shown.

Comment: print(contactsArray) or place a breakpoint to check the count of contactsArray